# How to derive this equation about chiral lagrangian?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, effective-field-theory

I'm learning chiral effective field theory from a paper.
The NG boson field are collected in the matrix form as
[image]

and the chiral fields U and u are defined by
[image]

When there is no other field, the chiral connection is defined as

[image]

I don't know why it can be rewritten as

[image]

Is it correct to expand u† as $u^{\dagger} =1-\frac{i \phi}{\sqrt{2}f }$ ?

Comment: [This is the link](https://www.tdx.cat/bitstream/handle/10803/459150/AFA_PhD_THESIS.pdf?sequence=7/) The equation 1.44 on page 32  and the one over 1.54 on page 37.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A(t)$ be a path in the space of invertible matrices parametrized by $t$. Then $A^{-1}(t)A(t) = 1$ for any $t$. It follows then that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} (A^{-1} A) = 0$ or in other words, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}A^{-1} \cdot A = - A^{-1} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} A$. Now recall that for unitary matrices $A^\dagger = A^{-1}$.